# WebP Duplicate Finder

Tags: images, duplicate-files

Is there an image duplicate finder program that works on Windows or Linux that can search a folder to find duplicates and near duplicates (different resolutions, compression modes, etc) in the WebP image format? I don't care if the program is freeware or costware. I want something just like the program [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page), which searches a batch of images for images that are the same picture. Visipics can even find duplicated images that have different dimensions. But Visipics doesn't work with the WebP image format. It's easy to find image duplicate finders, but I haven't been able to find one that works with WebP image files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all but the most recent copy of a file in a directory tree](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25990/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-copy-of-a-file-in-a-directory-tree)

Comment: @Kodiologist That answer doesn't address my needs. WebP isn't even mentioned in that answer, so I don't know why you think it would apply to this question.

Comment: @Izzy I just updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now! Will cleanup obsolete comments now. // As for the question linked: for a "bitwise comparison", the file format should be ignorable (files are either identical or not). So I take it you also want to deal with the same picture in different resolutions or compression levels – so the software should do a "similarity check"?

Comment: "WebP isn't even mentioned in that answer" — That doesn't mean it doesn't work with WebP. In particular, as @Izzy says, a program doesn't need to know anything about file fomats in order to find bit-for-bit identical files.

Comment: You could also convert your images to a more common format with e.g. ImageMagick.

Comment: @Kodiologist converting them all to find the dupes is not a recommended approach, as it first creates even more dupes :) But OP has a point if the tool should also find the same picture in (slightly) different resolutions or compression modes, keeping the best one (aka "master") only – which seems kind of what *VisiPics* offers. If that's a requirement we can of course only tell if OP lets us know :)

Comment: @Kodiologist I downloaded and tested the two programs, and they do indeed work with webp files. So that's great. They can find exact image duplicates, but unlike VisiPics they can't find near duplicates. So my question has been answered, to a degree, by that question. But I still want something like VisiPics that can find near duplicates (as Izzy says different resolutions, compression modes, etc).

Comment: I wish I was a programmer. I could maybe crack open the visipics code and add compatibility with webp files.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is:
[Duplicate Photo Finder](http://www.mindgems.com/products/VS-Duplicate-Image-Finder/VSDIF-About.htm)

I use it for years now and it is updated regularly.

[image]

Here is the list of the supported file format:
Supported file formats:

```
JPEG Bitmap (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe)
Compuserve Bitmap (*.gif)
Portable Network Graphics (*.png)
TIFF Bitmap (*.tif;*.tiff;*.fax;*.g3n;*.g3f)
JPEG2000 Files (*.jp2)
JPEG2000 Code Stream (*.j2k;*.jpc;*.j2c)
Targa (*.tga;*.targa;*.vda;*.icb;*.vst;*.pix)
Paintbrush (*.pcx)
Windows Bitmap (*.bmp;*.dib;*.rle)
Windows Metafile (*.wmf)
Enhanced Windows Metafile (*.emf)
Windows Icon (*.ico)
Windows Cursor (*.cur)
Wireless Bitmap (*.wbmp)
Portable Pixmap (*.pxm;*.ppm)
Adobe Photoshop (*.psd)
Camera RAW (*.crw; *.cr2; *.nef; *.raw; *.pef; *.raf; *.x3f; *.bay; *.orf; *.srf; *.mrw; *.dcr; *.sr2; *.dng; *.erf; *.mef; *.arw) (only in Pro and Corporate versions)
DICOM Images (*.dcm) (only in Corporate version)
HDPhoto Images (*.hdp; *.wdp; *.jxr) (only in Pro and Corporate versions)
WebP Images (*.webp) (only in Pro and Corporate versions)
```

Comment: Not disclosing any affiliation you have with the product you recomend is considered spam. Please be aware of that.

Comment: Hello "Williams Sarah".  Do you have any association with this product?  If so, please disclose in full.  Thank you!

Comment: Hello, as I noted I use the tool for many years now. I am also using their free Duplicate File Finder and Folder Size tools. I suggested a feature and they implemented it for me. They provided me a free bonus license once if that counts for affiliation - I do not think so.
I am really happy with the company. I recommend them whenever I can.